# Can covert 100% height to pixels

Tags: html, css, asp.net

In HTML using a div with height of 100% . instead of percentage, i need pixels. anyone know how to implement the 100% to pixel without giving any particular pix value?

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: No you can not convert 100% height to px in CSS, but you can in JS. What is your goal exactly? there might be another way to achieve it.

Comment: you'd need javascript, are you doing plain js or using a framework?

Comment: I think your are facing the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your goal is not to convert 100% to px, but something else you believe you can solve using this conversion. Please tell us what you are trying to achieve, and not only how you think you can solve the requirement.

Comment: Steve B : yes, exact problem is that overflow-y style is not working on IE10 because of 100% height. so i need to use both height 100% and Overflow-y =scroll

Comment: @Stefan :: in a div, iam using height 100%, i want to know that, it is possible to convert to pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload= total_y;
   function total_y(){
       var x = screen.height + "px";
    document.getElementById("bo").style.height= x ;    
    document.getElementById("bo").style.background= "red" ;
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body id="bo">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, you have to use JS. Maybe you can use this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
                padding: 0px; margin: 0px;
            }
            #foo{
                background-color: #ffff00;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var tHeight = $(window.top).height();
                alert("Visible screen height is " + tHeight + "px");
                $("#foo").height(tHeight);

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="foo">
            THERE YOU GO!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps